# Entity Reference In Web Service

Tags: web-services, entity-framework, asmx, generic-list

I have 2 tables in database one of them is employee and the other one is city. I created ado.net entity data model from database. I took a employe and i can access city of these. I am using web service and have a webmethod which return List. I selected employees and called ToList() method. I can not access city name in presentation layer which feeds by web service (asmx not wcf), only access in ID of city. how can i solve this problem.

Comment: Is City name a string property, or is do you have to navigate to a city entity to get it. Please show how you would access City Name from a City entity on the server. Also, FYI, it is not a best practice to return EF Entity types. You will be returning data from the base class that you do not want to have on the client.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .Include when retrieving your entity from EF to load navigation properties for your entity.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx heres the docs on .Include, if you have EF4.1 or above there is also a lambda version in an extension method which gives you type safety (Reference System.Data.Entity)